# Quicksort an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

**EDIT: I called my sorting method "quicksort" before but now thanks to you guys, I realize that was completely wrong. This is likely some type of selection sorting.**

Here in this constructor, I have an array of cards (the object array) and an int array that should correspond to the object array:

```
public Deck ()
{
    deck = new Card [52];
    deckNum = new int [52];

    for (int x = 0 ; x < 52 ; x++)  // for each card in standard deck
    {
        deck [x] = new Card (x); // create card
        deckNum [x] = x; // card number
    }

}
```

After that, I have a shuffle method which shuffles correctly so I also made it shuffle the corresponding int array:

```
 public void shuffle ()
{
    int value;
    int tempNum;
    Card temp;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < deck.length; x++) // goes through all cards
    {
      value = r.nextInt(x + 1); // random value

      //Shuffle Card array
      temp = deck[value]; // new array
      deck[value] = deck[x];
      deck[x] = temp;

   // Shuffle int array (not displayed)
      tempNum = deckNum[value];
      deckNum[value] = deckNum[x];
      deckNum[x] = tempNum;


    }
}
```

Now for the sorting method, which when I try to use, **ends up shuffling the cards again**.

```
  public void quickSort ()
{
    Card temp1;

    for (int x = 0 ; x < deck.length - 1 ; x++) //sort first length-1 values
    {
       int lowPos = x; // assume first value is lowest

  for (int y = x + 1 ; y < deck.length ; y++) {// check rest of list
    if (deckNum [y] < deckNum [lowPos]) // uses the int array to find a lower value
    {
    lowPos = y;// make it the lowest
    }
 }


      // swap low value with value in its proper position
      //uses card array again
      temp1 = deck [x]; 
      deck [x] = deck [lowPos];
      deck [lowPos] = temp1;
    }
}
```

You may only look through the quicksort method, but just in case, deckNum[] is the array that holds the integer values of the cards while the deck[] array holds the card objects which I am trying to manipulate.

The sorting method works when I use just an int array.

I may be completely wrong in using an int array but I honestly don't know any other way.  A little help would be great!

Comment: `Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(deck));`

Comment: I don't think this is how Quick Sort works

Comment: @CardinalSystem I think he wants to sort it by himself so we should focus on helping finding the bug. Nonetheless good hint in case OP didn't know that there are built-in sorts already.

Comment: *"quicksort method, which I'm sure is the correct way to do the method"* - Why do you think so? Take a look at [Wikipedia:Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and compare it to your version. Grab a paper and pencil and evaluate your method on a small example like `[2, 3, 1, 4]` and see what happens. You will then notice why it shuffles instead of sorting.

Comment: I have not tested this code. But I would start by putting braces around `lowPos = y;temp=1=deck[x]...`. Seems your code does the swap every time regardless of if condition check. In short, try putting braces around if body.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it worked when I used it before. Haven't actually checked it again.

Comment: instead of having two arrays, you can make your own `equals` function which compares then objects.

Comment: But what happens once it compares? Does it simply check if the cards are the same?

Comment: quicksort is a recursive algorithm.  Your implementation doesn't call itself recursively, so must be *fundamentally* wrong.  make sure you understand how quicksort works, and *why* it works, before trying to implement it: it's a sneaky algorithm that can be hard to understand if you aren't used to thinking recursively.

Comment: Oh, I see! I'm not sure where my misconception came from so thank you @Jules !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the array is not sorted is that the *deckNum* array is not sorted as the loop goes forward.

Try this:

```
public void quickSort () {
    Card temp1;
    int temp2;

    for (int x = 0 ; x < deck.length - 1 ; x++) //sort first length-1 values
    {
        int lowPos = x; // assume first value is lowest
        for (int y = x + 1 ; y < deck.length ; y++) // check rest of list
            if (deckNum [y] < deckNum [lowPos])
                lowPos = y; // make it the lowest

        temp1 = deck [x]; 
        deck [x] = deck [lowPos];
        deck [lowPos] = temp1;

        //Add the following to your code
        temp2 = deckNum [x]; 
        deckNum [x] = deckNum [lowPos];
        deckNum [lowPos] = temp2;
    }
}
```

As a side note, what you are implementing is NOT the quick sort algorithm. Take a look at the Wikipedia article referred to in the comments to learn how quick sort actually works.

Comment: Ohmygod, this was so simple! Thank you so much! And I see now that I didn't know what quicksort meant at all. I'll be trying to figure that out now then :D

Comment: A better way to implement this would be to have the *Card* class implement *Comparable* interface. Then you will not need another array and this type of error will be automatically avoided.